# contents of data partition in android

Tags: security, file-system, storage

does anyone know what all content is stored in /data or userdata partition in android-10.

I see a lot of directories in /data like app-staging, misc, system, vendor.

what information is stored in these directories and how to check whether these files are encrypted or not

Comment: there is no exhaustive explanation for each directory because OEM can store basically anything in */data*. but you can read at least some information about [apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data). regarding your second question check *ro.crypto.type* first https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/198065/file-based-encryption-security-and-backup-restore-considerations